# Significato di "scanno" in questo brano

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel racconto *Il paese*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Il medico rise gutturalmente e nient’altro, poi aspirò la prima boccata. – Maledetto Placido, – disse subito dopo, – non ti dà una sigaretta fumabile. E si capisce. Tiene il tabacco in bottega sotto lo **scanno** del sale, il sale trasuda e va a infettare il tabacco. Questa è chimica pura, signori.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "scanno" in questo passaggio? Nei dizionari che ho consultato non ho saputo trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo scanno è in piemontese una sorta di asse munito di due gambe di sostegno che veniva usata nelle botteghe anche come ripiano per poggiare la merce in vendita.

Treccani riporta anche la variante [scagno](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scagno/) che significa:

> Variante settentr. (presente anche in qualche altro dialetto) di
>   scanno, spec. nel sign. di sgabello; anche ufficio, negozietto.

[Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/scagno.html) riporta il seguente significato:

> s.m. (pl. -gni)
>
> 1 dial. Ufficio, studio del commerciante
>
> 2 ant. Scanno, scranna, sedile

[Questo dizionario di piemontese](http://alessandrialisondria.altervista.org/dialet-lissandren-dizionario-alessandrino-italiano/) riporta anche un altro significato:

> scàgn (s. m.). scranno, panca. Anche l’asse, munito di due gambe di
>   sostegno, usato dalle lavandaie per lavare i panni nelle rogge.

Comment: Ma uno "sgabello" non è un tipo di sedia? Anche "sedile", "panca", "scranna", ... sono oggetti per sedersi.

Comment: Vero, ma in passato gli scaffali delle botteghe, specie delle zone rurali erano simili a panche, cioè formati da due sostegni e un asse trasversale. Potevano anche essere sovrapposte l’una all’altra, come avveniva ad esempio dai panettieri.

Comment: Non ho a mano un dizionario lombardo, ma in Brianza "scagn" equivale a "cadrega" —  La mia ridente cittadina era un tempo nota come "ul paes di scagn" a causa della proliferazione di ditte concorrenti nel settore delle sedie.